# Failed to start project error in Visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, ssis-2012

Usually i run my integration packages from visual studio 2012,but today when i am trying to run the package i am getting the below error before validation.

[image]

Can anyone help me why i am getting this error and solution for this?

Comment: Seems like a crazy question but do you have Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate installed ?

Comment: No, I have VS 2012 professional installed